# am developing payroll project. i calculate leave detection but it show on error for Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim day1 As Double
    Dim lea As Double

    day1 = Val(TextBox1.Text / 30)
    lea = (CDbl(TextBox2.Text * day1))
    TextBox3.Text = lea
    Dim pf As Double
    Dim esi As Double
    Dim loan As Double
    Dim net As Double
    'Dim leave As Double
    'leave = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 2.0) / 100
    pf = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 4.0) / 100
    esi = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 3.0) / 100
    'TextBox2.Visible = True
    'TextBox3.Visible = True
    'TextBox4.Visible = True
    'TextBox5.Visible = True
    'TextBox6.Visible = True
    TextBox4.Text = CStr(pf)
    TextBox5.Text = CStr(esi)
    TextBox6.Text=0
    If TextBox1.Text > 0 Then
        loan = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 2.0) / 100
        TextBox6.Text = CStr(loan)
    End If

    net = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) - (TextBox3.Text + pf + esi + loan))

    'TextBox6.Text = CStr(net)
End Sub
```

Comment: error show on lea=(CDbl(TextBox2.Text * day1)) what i mistake here plz help this coding

Comment: VB.NET has better functions that handle conversion from string to double than the older one of VB6. Try to learn about Double.TryParse instead of using the Compatibility layer for VB6

Comment: where i declare double.tryparse. plz send  some example

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are in the wrong place.

Use:

```
day1 = Val(TextBox1.Text) / 30
lea = CDbl(TextBox2.Text) * day1
```

Comment: your coding are very useful for my project thank u so much friend.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a full answer because the variables used in your code don't help much to understand what you are trying to do, but as a suggestion, I will try to explain how to use [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx).

This method tries to convert the input from the user (textbox.text) in a double. If the conversion is successful then the passed double variable is initialized with the result of the conversion and the methods returns true. If the conversion fails the method return false.

```
.....
if Not double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, day1) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Not a valid number typed")
    return
End If

' Now with this line you don't get failed conversion from strings' 
day1 = day1 / 30

Dim temp As Double
if Not double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, temp) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Not a valid number typed")
    return
End If

' again no conversion problems here '
lea = temp  * day1

.... the rest of your code should reuse the conversion already made for 
.... textbox1.Text and textBox2.Text ....
```

And a last tip: You talk about a payroll system, so you are dealing with currency values. In this case it is much better to use decimal variables instad of doubles. Decimals are better to handle currency values and don't suffer from the rounding problems as floating point variables.
Also the decimal type has the TryParse method from its class methods.

Answer (score -1):

Dim day1 As Double

Dim lea As Double

day1 = Val(TextBox1.Text / 30)

lea = (CDbl(TextBox2.Text)) * (day1)

TextBox3.Text = CStr(lea)

Dim pf As Double

Dim esi As Double

Dim loan As Double

Dim net As Double

pf = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 4.0) / 100

esi = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 3.0) / 100

TextBox4.Text = CStr(pf)

TextBox5.Text = CStr(esi)

loan = (CDbl(TextBox6.Text) * 2.0) / 100

net = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text)) - (TextBox3.Text + pf + esi + loan)

TextBox7.Text = CStr(net)